# Is there a way to update a variable outside a method that is used as a parameter in said method?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I have 62 check boxes on 2 different panels.
30 of them on each panel are for selecting PC names while 1 on each selects all.

So on each of those 60 that are just selecting items I have this code:

```
private void HP04ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        setComponent(HP04, blrS,all_blr);
```

HP04 is the name of a checkbox for one of the PCs, blrS is the name of an int that counts how many checkboxes are selected(there is another int for the boxes on the other panel), all_blr is the name of the checkbox that selects all on the blr panel.

This is the method I used:

```
public void setComponent(javax.swing.JCheckBox  component, int room,javax.swing.JCheckBox  all)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Component: "+component.isSelected()); //testing to see if the method is actually being called
        if (component.isSelected()){ //if checkbox is checked
            room++; //records how many boxes are checked
            if (room == 30)
            {
                all.setSelected(true);//autochecks "all" check box if all PCs are selected
            }
            if (!messagearea.getText().equals(""))
            {
                sendb.setEnabled(true);//if any boxes are checked and the message area is populated, enable the button
            }
        }
        else
        {
            room--;//records how many boxes are checked
            all.setSelected(false);//unchecks the "all" check box if not all of them are checked
            if (room == 0)
            {
                sendb.setEnabled(false);//disables button if no PCs are selected to be messaged
            }
        }
        System.out.println(room); //testing int updates based on UI changes
    }
```

Now the problem is room is only fetching the value of whatever variable is put in that parameter and then room itself is being modified. So in the example `setComponent(HP04, blrS,all_blr);` blrS is never changed.

I know the code inside the method works, it worked before I decided to cut down on code by using a method, as before I had the code inside the method in the actionperformed for every checkbox before hand... Like this:

```
private void HP04ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        if (HP04.isSelected()){
            blrS++;
            if (blrS == 30)
            {
                all_blr.setSelected(true);
            }
            if (!messagearea.getText().equals(""))
            {
                sendb.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            blrS--;
            all_blr.setSelected(false);
            if (blrS == 0)
            {
                sendb.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(blrS);
    }
```

It's just understanding how parameters and methods works that is tripping me up.
It feels obvious that what I'm doing shouldn't work, room is a variable inside the method... But how do I change that?

Comment: Since `setComponent` is a method on the same object, it can access `blrS` and `all_blr`  without the need to receive them as parameters.

Comment: @Holger I don't understand.
The method is used for 60 different objects, half of which use ```crS``` and ```all_cr``` instead of those other 2. If your point still stands, how would I make use of what you have said? What do I do differently?

Comment: That’s what OOP is for. Design a class to handle *one* group, then create *two objects* of that class.

Comment: @Holger I don't know how to do that lol, I did some Java in high school 10 years ago and now I decided to try making an app to make my job easier... Can you give me some help with that or refer me to a resource that might fit my needs?

Comment: Why not return `room` from the method, and assign it to the variable when you call it? `blrS = setComponent(HP04, blrS, all_blr);`

Comment: Note that the way your method is written, is already inconsistent, as you are changing the enabled status of `sendb` regardless of which checkbox group you are processing, without considering the status of the other group. Creating classes and objects is the thing you should understand before even starting. You may [make the tour](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) to refresh your memories. Generally, it’s not a good idea to use a UI building tool as starting point and try to fill in the code, you should rather start with the application logic and then add the user interface…

Comment: @Holger the panels are on a tabbed pane, so all cr checkboxes are disabled when you switch to the blr pane and the converse is also true, so only one group of checkboxes is processed at a time and the ints blrS and crS are set to zero when I switch panes.
RobSpoor's solution worked though, thank you. And I'll definitely look into those tutorials.

How do I mark this question as solved now?

Comment: Since there are no answers posted, you could simply delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

"Why not return room from the method, and assign it to the variable when you call it? `blrS = setComponent(HP04, blrS, all_blr);`"
– Rob Spoor (in the comments to this post)